# Where Clause using another Dimension Value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to create a Calculated Member in my cube with where clause but couldn't figure how to achieve the proper result.

I created a calculated member "Outlook" using the below code to display only Forecast values.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Outlook]
 AS SUM(([Source Profile].[Source Profile Hierarchy].CurrentMember,
         [Source Profile].[Profile Level01].&[Outlook]),
        [Measures].[USD Amount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;(#,##0)", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'USD' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'CARS';
```

[Cube Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcc4G.jpg)

Now I would like to filter the results dynamically based on another hidden dimension "Current_Month".  This dimension always has current financial period value and it's corresponding outlook profile

```
Year_Month  Outlook_Profile
2015010     10 + 2
```

Expected result should be "Outlook" measure showing value based on Current_Month dimension, which is '10 + 2' and rest of them should be 0

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi3Qv.png)

Just to explain the requirement in SQL terms, I would like to achieve the below in MDX

```
Where Fact.Source_Profile=Dimension.Source_Profile
```

instead of

```
Where Fact.Source_Profile='10 + 2'
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this in Where Clause or by another means.  I could see examples of hard coding values, like year.&[2015] but haven't seen one using dynamic values.

Comment: I'm not sure if I posted my question clearly :(  All I would like to do is (in SQL terms) Where Fact.Source Profile = Dimension.Source Profile.  The  Dimension.Source Profile changes every month and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself and thought of sharing the same.  Used StrToMember function to pass hidden dimension's member as a variable here.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Outlook]
 AS (
        Sum
            (
                (
                    [Source Profile].[Source Profile Hierarchy].CurrentMember,
                    strtomember("[Source Profile].[Source Name].&[" + [Outlook Profile].[Outlook Profile].&[1].Member_Caption + "]")
                )
            ,[Measures].[USD Amount]
        )
), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;(#,##0)", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'USD' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'CARS'  ;
```